# Cannot set tp_smapi thresholds on a Thinkpad

Tags: 11.10, thinkpad

I have a thinkpad edge 13, with the package `tp-smapi-dkms` installed. As described in [these instructions](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi), I have also run `sudo modprobe tp_smapi`, and added `tp_smapi` to `/etc/modules`

Before upgrade to 11.10, I used to be able to change thresholds for stopping battery charging. I would open the file `/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh` as administrator and change the value from 100 to 85. Now, I am no longer able to directly edit that file. I also tried `sudo echo 85 > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh` but get `Permission denied`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do as showing below:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo XX > /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh'
```

But I also suffer from trouble in ThinkPad X201s + Ubuntu 11.10.

1. Battery keeps discharging while I connect my ThinkPad X201s to AC adapter.
2. Before update Ubuntu, charge_thresh values are shared with Windows configuration.
   But after upgrade, the value of threshold are initialized to 95 & 100 while it is
   configured to 75 & 95 in Windows.