# How do I load the tp_smapi kernel module on a Lenovo Easypad?

Tags: battery, lenovo, modprobe, tp-smapi

I own a [Lenovo EasyPad Z580](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/laptop/ideapad/z-series/z580/) running Ubuntu and I'd like to manage more of the power management (battery). I found answers in this question about battery management on Lenovo systems: [How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)

So, I've installed [tp smapi](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi) using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms
```

[Aquaherd's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/72570/88802) seems to settle the problem for some users. In the comments however it is clear it throws the following error for other users (me included):

```
sudo modprobe tp_smapi
FATAL: Error inserting tp_smapi (/lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/tp_smapi.ko):
 No such device
```

DKMS reports (`dkms status`):

```
tp-smapi, 0.41, 3.5.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I checked the following sources, but they all seem too advanced for me. Is there a way to install tp_smapi without messing too much with kernels and source code etc? If there is not, can someone explain the various steps proposed in some of these *howto's*

- [Cannot set tp_smapi thresholds on a Thinkpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71767/cannot-set-tp-smapi-thresholds-on-a-thinkpad)
- http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2007/09/howto-extend-life-of-your-thinkpads.html
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1752993
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1752993
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11670/how-to-load-tp-smapi-on-thinkpad-x120e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I believe you have an Ideapad Z580 rather than an Easypad (which seems not to exist).*

#### Steps are correct

All seems to be installed and enabled well. You've installed the correct DKMS package (`tp-smapi-dkms`) and you're `modprobe`'ing correct.

#### `tp_smapi` is for real Thinkpads only

Not for Ideapads. And not even all Thinkpads are supported. See [this page on Thinkwiki.org](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi) which models are supported. It doesn't even mention any Ideapad there.

From the same [Thinkwiki.org page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi):

> The ThinkPad SL series and IdeaPad series have firmware that is completely different from other ThinkPad models. Neither tp_smapi nor thinkpad-acpi support these models.

These are consumer-grade notebooks, from the original Lenovo line. The supported Thinkpads are more of the original IBM-line of machines with a completely different design in hardware. The component that's key here is the embedded hardware controller for this unique power controlling feature. As far as I know, only the business-line of Thinkpads still feature this today.

Short history: Lenovo [bought](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad) IBM's Thinkpad line of machines in 2005, but even till today the machines between the Thinkpad T/X/W series can't be compared to the consumer-grade machines in terms of compatibility (and quality).

#### Bottom line: you can't do this on your device.